# WCF Multiple Endpoints is not working

Tags: wcf

I am trying to let my WCF service to have operations that can be called through a proxy client and through REST call, i am using the following configurations:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="SecureBehavior" name="Payment">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="secureWS" contract="IPayment"/>
    <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" contract="IPayment"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
  <bindings>
    <mexHttpBinding>
      <binding name="userMex"/>
    </mexHttpBinding>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="secureWS">
        <security mode="Message">
          <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
      <binding name="publicWS">
        <security mode="None"/>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SecureBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        <serviceCredentials>
          <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="false"/>
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
      <behavior name="PublicBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        <serviceCredentials>
          <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="true"/>
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</services>
```

and here is my code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPayment
{
    [OperationContract]
    PaymentResult Finalize(string TransactionID, string CertificatePath);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "rest")]
    System.IO.Stream GetPayment();
}
```

Now whenever i run my service i receive this error:

> Operation 'Finalize' of contract 'IPayment' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.

Where here i would like to keep Finalize operation to be only called via .NET client and the GetPayment operation to be called through any browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want your Finalize method to be called from a client connecting via the webhttp endpoint and you don't want GetPayments to be called from a client connecting via wshttp you can simply split your contract in two.

Assuming you are hosting in IIS you might need to do a little trick to make sure that it works.  Let me give you an example using the details from the question...

First of all here is the code for the two services...

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPayment
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "rest")]
    System.IO.Stream GetPayment();
}

[DataContract]
public class PaymentResult
{
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMakePayment
{
    [OperationContract]
    PaymentResult Finalize(string TransactionID, string CertificatePath);
}

// Maybe you really should have the two services separate but if you do
// want to implement them both in a single class you can do this
public abstract class PaymentBase : IMakePayment, IPayment
{
    // ... Implement both interfaces here
    public PaymentResult Finalize(string TransactionID, string CertificatePath)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public System.IO.Stream GetPayment()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class MakePayment : PaymentBase
{
    // Empty
}

public class Payment : PaymentBase
{
    // Empty
}
```

Now create two .svc files like so:

**MakePayment.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WebApplication1.MakePayment"  %>
```

**Payment.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WebApplication1.Payment" %>
```

And finally here is the system.servicemodel configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>      
    <service behaviorConfiguration="SecureBehavior" name="WebApplication1.MakePayment">        
      <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureWS" contract="WebApplication1.IMakePayment"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" bindingConfiguration="userMex"/>
    </service>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="PublicBehavior" name="WebApplication1.Payment">
      <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" bindingConfiguration="publicWS" contract="WebApplication1.IPayment"/>
    </service>      
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <mexHttpBinding>
      <binding name="userMex"/>
    </mexHttpBinding>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="secureWS">
        <security mode="Message">
          <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="publicWS">
        <security mode="None"/>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SecureBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        <serviceCredentials>
          <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="false"/>
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
      <behavior name="PublicBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        <serviceCredentials>
          <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="true"/>
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

There you go - if you connect to /MakePayment.svc you will connect via WSHTTP and be able to call FinalizePayment and if you go to /Payments.svc/rest it will call the GetPayment method where you are returning a stream.

Comment: i did it this way, but now am having a new error: Endpoint not found, any idea?

Comment: Updated with a more concrete example

Comment: now am lost :)
let me traverse your code and see, thank you anyway.